# using the spectral decomposition of a matrix

Tags: matrices

if I have 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{-}1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am given the characteristic values are 
$$
\lambda_{1}=1 \text{ and } \lambda_{2}=2 
\text{ and A is similar to a characteristic polynomial}
$$
I have found the spectral decomposition of A.
I now need to use this to find 
$$2^{A}$$
how do I do this?

Comment: what do you mean $A$ is similar to its characteristic polynomial by the way?

Answer (score 1):

If $A = SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$, say,

$$D = \left(\begin{matrix}
         \lambda_{1} & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & \lambda_{2} & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} \\
     \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then

$$ 2^{A} = S\left(\begin{matrix}
         2^{\lambda_{1}} & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 2^{\lambda_{2}} & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 2^{\lambda_{3}} \\
     \end{matrix}\right)S^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply out the decomposition, substituting $\lambda_i \to 2^{\lambda_i}$.

Comment: I worked out the spectral decomposition to be $$A=E_{1} + 2E_{2} $$ now if I am going to subsitute using the function $$2^{A}$$ do I say $$ 2^{A} = 2E_{1}+2^{2}E_{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $A=VDV^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue decomposition of $A$, then $f(A) = Vf(D)V^{-1}$.